# Is this a bug in GNU make's `filter`?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile that starts like this:

```
CORE_PATH:=$(filter %/makefile_ltlibs.inc,$(MAKEFILE_LIST))

foobar:
        @echo "MAKEFILE_LIST = \"$(MAKEFILE_LIST)\""
        @echo "filter = \"$(filter %/makefile_ltlibs.inc,$(MAKEFILE_LIST))\""
        @echo "CORE_PATH = \"$(CORE_PATH)\""
```

and when I run `gmake foobar` I get the follow output:

```
MAKEFILE_LIST = " GNUmakefile ../../matrixssl.test/crypto/Makefile ../common.mk ../core/makefiles/detect-and-rules.mk ../../matrixssl.test/crypto/makefile.inc makefile ../../matrixssl.test/crypto/makefile_ltlibs.inc"
filter = "../../matrixssl.test/crypto/makefile_ltlibs.inc"
CORE_PATH = ""
```

How is it possible that `CORE_PATH` is empty here?!

EDIT:

I made it into a self-contained test case:

```
FILTER_LIST1 := " foo bar"
FILTER_LIST2 := " foo bar "

WORD11 := $(filter foo,$(FILTER_LIST1))
WORD12 := $(filter bar,$(FILTER_LIST1))

WORD13 := $(filter foo,"$(FILTER_LIST1) ")
WORD14 := $(filter bar,"$(FILTER_LIST1) ")

WORD21 := $(filter bar,$(FILTER_LIST2))

foobar:
        @echo "FILTER_LIST1 = \"$(FILTER_LIST1)\""
        @echo "FILTER_LIST2 = \"$(FILTER_LIST2)\""
        @echo "WORD11 = \"$(WORD11)\""
        @echo "WORD12 = \"$(WORD12)\""
        @echo "WORD13 = \"$(WORD13)\""
        @echo "WORD14 = \"$(WORD14)\""
        @echo "WORD21 = \"$(WORD21)\""
```

outputs

```
FILTER_LIST1 = " foo bar"
FILTER_LIST2 = " foo bar "
WORD11 = "foo"
WORD12 = ""
WORD13 = "foo"
WORD14 = ""
WORD21 = "bar"
```

My conclusion is that `filter` is broken for the last entry.
Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue with `MAKEFILE_LIST` comes from the fact that this variable gets extended each time `make` process an `include` directive. Now, your use of `:=` for setting the value of `CORE_PATH` tells `make` to evaluate the expression right away. Since you are at the start of your `Makefile`, at this point `MAKEFILE_LIST` only contains `Makefile` (see the example given in the [description of the variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html#index-MAKEFILE_005fLIST-_0028list-of-parsed-makefiles_0029)), and the filter returns empty.

On the other hand, the recipe is evaluated once the `Makefile` has been completely parsed. Hence you have there a much longer sequence in `MAKEFILE_LIST`, and you can filter it. To obtain the same thing with `CORE_PATH`, define it with `CORE_PATH = ...`. The definition will then only be expanded when `CORE_PATH` is used, not when it is defined (see [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors) for more information about these two "flavors" of variables).

Regarding your edit, as mentioned by Vroomfondel, `FILTER_LIST1` consists in 3 words (you can see that by doing `$(words $(FILTER_LIST1))`, `"`, `foo` and `bar"`, none of them being `bar`. Similarly, `FILTER_LIST2` has 4 words, `"`, `foo`, `bar` and `"`, and `bar` can be found in the list.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I gave the value of my `MAKEFILE_LIST`, from which you can conclude that this is *not* the first Makefile (it is `../../matrixssl.test/crypto/makefile_ltlibs.inc` as you can see from the value of MAKEFILE_LIST, which gets included at some point). The use of `:=` is not the problem, if I try to get a word from the middle of `MAKEFILE_LIST` it works as expected.

Comment: Hmm, I guess you must be right somehow. I am following a different approach now though, so can't test it anymore... But it makes sense that MAKEFILE_LIST does not contain the value that I'm looking for at the moment CORE_PATH is set, while it does when I execute the foobar target.

Comment: Please re-read carefully Virgile's first and second paragraphs.  If you understand those paragraphs then you'll completely understand the behavior.  If you really want to see the value of `MAKEFILE_LIST` at the time that `CORE_PATH` is set, you can't print it from a recipe.  You can add something like `$(info MAKEFILE_LIST = $(MAKEFILE_LIST))` just before or after you set `CORE_PATH` (not in a recipe) to see the value there.